# Sharing resources between Java projects in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, resources, client-server

I am making a game using a client-server model. Currently I have 3 projects: client, server, and common. Currently all of the resources for the game are in a folder inside the common project, which is recognised as a source folder by Eclipse.

This allows me to access the resources from within the client and server projects using:

```
InputStream in = SomeClass.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(filename);
```

The problem is that this method only works for reading the files, but I want to be able to write to these files, too (e.g. saving a level in the level editor).

I'm imagining the built project looking something like this:

- Game/resources/...
- Game/client.jar
- Game/server.jar

Can anyone recommend a way that I can configure my project so that Eclipse will build it in this way, or in such a way that both the client and server will be able to access the shared resources?

Comment: Why not use ant or maven? Why rely on eclipse?

Comment: Until now Eclipse has been adequate for my purposes. Are you suggesting that ant or maven would be able to achieve what I want? Which would you recommend?

Comment: Yes. I would recommend using ant or maven. Infact, eclipse has a feature that allows you to generate a basic ant script which you can then modify to satisfy your needs.