# Using Maven for a client-server project with external dependencies

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, client-server

I am working on a game that is split into 3 projects: client, server and common. Until now I have always relied on Eclipse to handle the build process, but as my project becomes more complicated I am considering using Maven (see my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29703607/sharing-resources-between-java-projects-in-eclipse)). I have begun looking into this, but I already have a lot of questions, and it's becoming a little overwhelming.

1. What would be the best way to structure such a project using Maven? Should each of my current projects become a separate Maven project? Or perhaps the common project should become a parent to the client and server projects? Or should all 3 of my projects become one giant super-project?
2. My client project has a dependency on a couple of external JAR files; how do I set up this dependency in Maven? The documentation suggests that I need a groupId and artifactId, etc. Where do I find these? Does this system rely on the JARs being catalogued in some (remote or local) repository?
3. I have a bunch of resources within the common project. I want these to be placed in the output directory as part of the build process, *not* inside the resulting JAR file. I read somewhere that all files in Maven's src/main/resources directory are automatically copied into the JAR file, so where else can I put them?
4. The documentation explains how to use Maven on the command line to build the project. If I am developing in Eclipse, is the command line still the preferred way to run Maven, or will a plugin such as M2Eclipse achieve the same thing?

Evidently my understanding of Maven is quite weak, so any advice / explanations / tutorials would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Common should be a simple maven java project.

The others would depend on the technologies used. If they are all java applications ie they have a main method that starts them then they would also be simple maven java projects. Otherwise they may be Web projects or some other type.  These types are made easy by maven prototypes. You can assess these when creating new maven projects in eclipse.

The client and server projects would both include common as a dependency.

The issue of parent project is about making dependencies and other maven settings consistent across multiple projects. If this is an issue for you then you probably want all 3 projects to reference the same parent so that you can manage these settings for all projects at once.

The remaining question is whether you are building all projects at once or managing versions separately. If you are compiling all at once and changing versions all at once you probably want a controlling project that includes all the others as modules.

It is common to make the child projects of a parent project also be modules of that parent. This should work in your relatively simple case.

The external libraries that your projects require are added as dependencies. The simplest way to do this is to search for them on maven central and cut and paste the provided maven pom snippet into you pom file. If they are not in maven central you should be able to find them in some other repository look in the providers doc to see if they list repositories.

If they are not in any repository you can install them manually in your local repository.